# Get anchor tag values in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, anchor

I have a html tag like this.

```
<a class="employee_details" target="_blank" href="index1.php?name=user1&id=123">User</a>
```

I need to get the two parameter values in jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.employee_details').click(function () {
            var status_id = $(this).attr('href').split('name');
            alert(status_id[0]);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help in getting both the parameter values in two variables in javascript.

I want to get user1 and 123 in two variables using jQuery

Thanks
Kimz

Comment: You want to get `user1` and `123`?

Comment: Yes - You are right. Help me out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#see_also) as a most up-to-date and modern solution:

```
let href = $(this).attr('href');
let pars = new URLSearchParams(href.split("?")[1]);

console.log(pars.get('name'));
```

Supported in all modern browsers and no jQuery needed!

**Original answer:**

Try this logic:

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
var result = {};
var pars = href.split("?")[1].split("&");

for (var i = 0; i < pars.length; i++)
{
    var tmp = pars[i].split("=");
    result[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
}

console.log(result);
```

So you'll get the parameters as properties on `result` object, like:

```
var name = result.name;
var id = result.id;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hr9N7/).

---

An implemented version:

```
var getParams = function(href)
{
    var result = {};
    var pars = href.split("?")[1].split("&");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < pars.length; i++)
    {
        var tmp = pars[i].split("=");
        result[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    }
    
    return result;
};

$('.employee_details').on('click', function (e) {
    var params = getParams($(this).attr("href"));
    console.log(params);
    
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hr9N7/1/).

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function() {
    $('.employee_details').on("click",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevents default action
        var status_id = $(this).attr('href');
        var reg = /name=(\w+).id=(\w+)/g;
        console.log(reg.exec(status_id)); // returns ["name=user1&id=123", "user1", "123"]
    });
});

// [0] returns `name=user1&id=123`
// [1] returns `user1`
// [2] returns `123`
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hc8PX/)

**NOTE:** Better to use [ON](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method instead of click

Answer (score 1):

Not the most cross browser solution, but probably one of the shortest:

```
$('.employee_details').click(function() {
    var params = this.href.split('?').pop().split(/\?|&/).reduce(function(prev, curr) {
        var p = curr.split('=');
        prev[p[0]] = p[1];
        return prev;
    }, {});

    console.log(params);
});
```

Output:

```
Object {name: "user1", id: "123"}
```

If you need IE7-8 support this solution will not work, as there is not `Array.reduce`.

Comment: Wow, I though I was the only one who could provide a solution that was not locked on only get two fixed params. +1

Comment: Yes, you will get object of all GET parameters. However I like your solution better, simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('.employee_details').click(function () {
        var query = $(this).attr('href').split('?')[1];
        var vars = query.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
            var pair = vars[i].split('=');
            var varName = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]);
            var varValue = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
            if (varName == "name") {
                alert("name = " + varValue);
            } else if (varName == "id") {
                alert("id = " + varValue);
            }
        }            
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very elegant, but here it is!

```
var results = new Array();
var ref_array = $(".employee_details").attr("href").split('?');
if(ref_array && ref_array.length > 1) {
    var query_array = ref_array[1].split('&');
    if(query_array && query_array.length > 0) {
        for(var i = 0;i < query_array.length; i++) {
            results.push(query_array[i].split('=')[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

In `results` has the values. This should work for other kinds of url querys.

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple

```
// function to parse url string
function getParam(url) {
    var vars = [],hash;
    var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}

// your code
$(function () {
    $('.employee_details').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var qs = getParam($(this).attr('href'));
        alert(qs["name"]);// user1
        var status_id = $(this).attr('href').split('name');
    });
});
```